# encode url in javascript like UrlEncode method of asp.net does

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a requirement to encode the url in javascript and in redirected page i can't use javascript so i must decode the url back in code. so i needs a javascript encode method which encodes url like URLEncode method of asp.net so that i can decode it in code with UrlDecode method

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript encodeURI() Function
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURI.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(escape("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470255/encode-url-in-javascript-like-urlencode-method-of-asp-net-does"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two native options: [encodeURI()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) or [encodeUriComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)